Nested Power BI Bookmarks
I am working on a project where my boss wants to see Net Sales $, Net Sales Units, Gross Margin $ and Gross Margin %, and seeing how each is doing this year, how we are doing vs Last year, and how we are doing vs budget.
What I envision is almost like a matrix (see below), and depending on what was chosen, determines the visual presented. I also want to keep it clean, so having slicers in the background is a must, if at all possible.
Actuals| Vs LY| Vs Budget|
Net Sales ||||
GM $      ||||
Net Units ||__||
GM %      |||__________|
I have tried creating bookmarks for every event, but it overrides the previous attempt. I have also asked fellow coworkers for help, and we tried coding, but nothing has worked.
I am not sure if this is possible, but any help/confirmation would be greatly appreciated.

Why not use parameters and let your boss choose which measures he wants to see at the same time? (You could even let him change the granularity of the x-axis... and none of it is hard at all).

Consider creating for potential solutioners a tiny dataset which, if solved will render into the greater solution.  More folks would scoop that data up, throw it in their PowerBI, and be off.  I am wildly successful with such approach, and am excited to see what's next!
